# how to encode the url when directing to another page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to encode the url of every pages of my website and I also want to encode the url of the first page of my websites.By google I got to know that we should use server.urlencode or httputility.urlencode but I didn't understand how to use that.I hope I get here answers with some lines codes.

Comment: Can you show some code that describes the problem? Why do you need to encode the url?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman:Like If I redirect using Respoonse.Redirect("Default.aspx") where should I use server.urlencode.I want to encode url so that no one can enter to my pages by typing in url.

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of `UrlEncode`.  It will take a string and change characters that cannot be represented in a Url and encode them so that they can.

Comment: See the MSDN example here to give you a better idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Aaron Palmer:Ok that means I can use that if I passes any information in url?Can you say me how?And also how to solve my problem mentioned above.

Comment: @user3079437 READ what he just typed. You cannot use `UrlEncode` to do what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Your comment: "I want to encode url so that no one can enter to my pages by typing in url." doesn't make sense.  The entire purpose of a URL is to identify the location of a page on the web.  If you want to implement some level of security, that should be done via other means.

Comment: Yes I am concerning about security.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in not understanding what UrlEncode does.

I replaces an url like this (note the space)

```
http://url/page 1.aspx
```

To (note replaced space with %20)

```
http://url/page%201.aspx
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info about this.

For more info about securing pages so unauthorized users cannot access them see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on MSDN.

Example for your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Default.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/> <!-- allow non-authorized and authorized users -->
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
   <location path="next.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/> <!-- deny non-authorized users -->
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Response.Redirect("default.aspx"?id=dt.Rows[0][0]); Now in this case can I hide the name of page and that id?

Comment: I wonder why you want to 'hide' the url from the user. The device is called a browser and preventing users for seeing a url is non-working security solution. The whole point is that anyone can enter it by hand. If you want users to prevent to enter a url, use some kind of authentication on your pages.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a reference for authorization.

Comment: My first page have address as (www.mywebsites.com/default.aspx) and next page have address as (www.mywebsites.com/next.aspx).Now if someone types "www.mywebsites.com/next.aspx" then he should be allow to enter that page or not?I am begineers in .net and really dont have idea about it and which mechanism should be used to make websites more secure?Thankyou